# web application interface optimisation - fonts / tips?

Tags: user-interface, fonts

I'm building an interface with a lot of info on the screen.. dozens of inputs, with accompanying labels. as a result of the volume of info the fonts have necessarily become pretty small.

but I'd like this to be as readable and usable as possible.. is there a really nice font that's both readable and compact, that works well in a browser (specifically in this case, IE7) ?

anyone have any other tips to sort this out? is there some specific combination of pixel/em size and font, or some other CSS voodoo that can help me out?

this is an intranet app so we actually can be pretty specific.

any suggestions appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this post from 2006:
http://www.kathymarks.com/archives/2006/11/best_fonts_for_the_web_1.html

Tahoma could be winner:

"Tahoma (Windows). Tahoma was designed especially for legibility on the screen. It's preloaded on Windows systems. Similar in style to Verdana, it is narrower and more condensed"

Answer (score 3):

To have it resized cross browser, use ems. Set your font-size on body element to be 62.5% to make sizing ems clearer. 1.2em  = 12px.

Arial is pretty good font. So is Helvetica.

Answer (score 0):

Do you keep accessibility in mind? Isn't it possible to redesign the interface so that less information is shown and people with less than 20/20 vision can easily read your pages?

Typically, sans serif fonts are more readable when used with small sizes. If you want to use a monospaced font, I personally quite like Vista's 'consolas' font.

Comment: honestly, i'd love to overhaul the interface, as you're correct it does need it. but at the moment i'm looking for a quick win in the legibility stakes